# Plotting a Parametric Curve in MatLab with a Double

Tags: matlab, graph, parametric-equations

I am trying to plot the parametric equation (t, -4, t^2 + 17), but am running into difficulties. I have been trying

```
fplot3(t, -4, t.^2+17)
```

But am getting the following error: Undefined function 'fplot3' for input arguments of type
'double'.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

[`fplot3`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot3.html) expects [anonymous functions](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) as inputs. So, you can use

```
fplot3(@(t) t,  @(t) -4,  @(t) t.^2+17)
```

Note the use of [`.^`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html), which is element-wise power.

The above works, but gives a warning

> `Warning: Function fails on array inputs. Use element-wise operators to increase speed.`

The reason is that the second function outputs a scalar, instead of an array the same size as the input `t`. To solve this, replace that function as follows:

```
fplot3(@(t) t,  @(t) repmat(-4, size(t)),  @(t) t.^2+17)
```

Also, you can specify the range of `t` as a fourth input:

```
fplot3(@(t) t,  @(t) repmat(-4, size(t)),  @(t) t.^2+17,  [-10 10])
```

[image]